# How to make for loop wait for all async functions to finish. async functions has multiple async functions inside in it

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, synchronization

I have an array, like [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10].

I like to process one item at a time. **synchronously.**

I have mixed with **non-async** functions too.

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for(i=0; i< array.length; i++){
    var result = await fun1(array[i]);
    console(result) //expecting print out 2,4,6,8,10...20 synchronously
}

async function fun1(item){
    return fun2(item);
}
async function fun2(item){
    a = new A(item)
    return a.hello()
}

class A{
    constructor(item){
       this.item = item;
    }

    hello(){
        //do something
        return this.item * 2;
    }
}
```

How can I make it happen in Node.JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Promise.all feature.

```
const promises = [];
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
array.forEach((num)=>{
  promises.push(func1(num))
});

Promise.all(promises)
.then(response => console.log(response)); // your required response
```